# how to view public properties/attributes of the aura/lwc component in managed packages?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, managed-package, aura, public-reactive-properties

how to view public properties/attributes of the aura/lwc component in managed packages?

For Example:

I want to use *SomeNamespace:componentName* in my markup/my component. I want to see the publicly available properties. Is there a declarative or coding way to view them?

```
<!-- calling the managed package component in myCustomComponent -->    
<SomeNamespace:componentName ?????=""></SomeNamespace:componentName>
```

Comment: Refer to this: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/291514/how-can-i-enable-api-properties-in-managed-packages-for-my-lightning-web-compon

Answer (score 0):

@Matt Lacey - that's fine, I did upvote the question but I was hoping to draw some more attention to it.

I found an answer! You can see *exposed* properties (a subset of public properties) by using the Tooling API (via Workbench, Salesforce Inspector, etc.) to view the `TargetConfigs` property of the [LightningComponentBundle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_lightningcomponentbundle.htm) object
[image] [image]